# SIP digest authorization что я делаю не так?

Tags: node.js, sip

Мне нужно изобразить исходящий вызов по SIP с сервера. Использую [sip.js](https://github.com/kirm/sip.js) и [MicroSIP](http://www.microsip.org/) для сравнения.
Собираю INVITE-сообщение, отсылаю, получаю 407, пытаюсь вычислить response для digest auth, и не получается( Получаю 403, тогда как MicroSIP нормально регистрируется и звонит. С помощью wiresharkа я проследил отличия - они есть в `via`,`call-id`, `tag` в поле `from`, `seq` разные + MicroSIP добавляет пару опциональных заголовков. Это все не влияет на авторизацию (так и должно быть) - проблема явно в вычислении `response` для digest auth.

```
function md5(string){
    return require('crypto').createHash('md5').update(string).digest('hex');
}
var to='sip:'+number+'@'+config.sip_options.host;
var q=res.headers['proxy-authenticate'][0];//res - это полученное сообщение с 407 статусом 
var cnonce=md5(q.nonce);
```

Пробовал с помощью [digest](https://github.com/kirm/sip.js/wiki/SIP.js-API#digest-authentication):

```
var digest=require('sip/digest');
var response=digest.calculateDigest({
    ha1:digest.calculateHA1({
        userhash:digest.calculateUserRealmPasswordHash(config.sip_options.user, q.realm, config.sip_options.password),
        nonce:q.nonce,
        cnonce:cnonce
    }),
    nonce:q.nonce,
    nc:'00000001',
    cnonce:cnonce,
    qop:'auth',
    method:'INVITE',
    uri:to
});
```

Не сработало. Почитал [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-22.4), попробовал самостоятельно воспроизвести все телодвижения:

```
var ha1=md5(config.sip_options.user+':'+q.realm+':'+config.sip_options.password)
var ha2=md5('INVITE'+':'+to);
var response2 = md5(ha1+':'+q.nonce+':'+'00000001'+':'+cnonce+':'+q.qop+':'+ha2);
```

Хэши получаются разные и оба не подходят. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в деталях, а помог случай. Как оказалось, sip.js странно парсит хедеры. Когда я заменил в варианте с digest 
    `qop:'auth',`
на
    `qop:q.qop,`
(напомню, что `var q=res.headers['proxy-authenticate'][0];`)
хэши вдруг стали совпадать. Это навело меня на мысль, что `q.qop!='auth'`, и когда я вывел его в консоль я увидел `'"auth"'` - вот такой вот парсер у `sip.js`. Убрав лишние кавычки - 
                `for(var i in q)q[i]=q[i].replace(/\"/g,'');`
Авторизация прошла, я увидел долгожданный 183 Session Progress и поток 200 Ok.